# Understanding the timing values from Charles debugging proxy

Tags: performance, http, charles-proxy

[image]

This image from Charles shows some pretty interesting information:

- Duration
- Request Duration
- Response Duration
- Latency

I'd like to better understand what these terms actually mean.

ie.,  How does Charles measure the request duration?  (In the course of a HTTP transaction, this is the time from when-to-when?)  Likewise for response.

Also, `request + response != Duration`.  Is the remainder server-side processing time?

What is Latency a measure of here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/chart/):

> - Request - the time spent sending (uploading) the request (dark blue)
> - Latency - the time spent waiting for network latency or processing
>     time on the server (mid blue)
> - Response - the time spent receiving
>     (downloading) the response (light blue)